# stop 2nd question after save to XML format?

Tags: asp.net, xml, excel, save

How can i get my Excel xls file that is password protected to stop asking me if i want to convert it to an XML file format?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about asp.net, but in VBA I would use this line of code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```